# jquery each fill elements gradually from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each, element

Hello I would like to fill gradually span elements with values of array. Can you help me please?

```
<span class="gt"></span>
<span class="gt"></span>
<span class="gt"></span>

var array=["apple","banana","cucumber"];

$("span.gt").each(function(){
    $(this).text(array[?]);
});
```

Output should look like this:

```
<span class="gt">apple</span>
<span class="gt">banana</span>
<span class="gt">cucumber</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the `index` value in the function for `each` loop. And since the number of `span` elements is equal to the number of items in the `array` variable you can use that `index` value to set the array values in the `span` elements:

```js
var array=["apple","banana","cucumber"];

$("span.gt").each(function(index){
    $(this).text(array[index]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="gt"></span>
<span class="gt"></span>
<span class="gt"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use for loop.
2. Use the increment number as index of the span and index of array

```js
var array = ["apple", "banana", "cucumber"];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  $('span').eq(i).text(array[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="gt"></span>
<span class="gt"></span>
<span class="gt"></span>
```